# Clarifying my Understanding of Encapsulation in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, encapsulation

I've been trying to figure out encapsulation for the past couple days and was wondering if my understanding is correct.

Is encapsulation when you make a class or a struct, make private variables and methods inside of the class or struct that you don't want other classes or structs to access, and then create public methods to read, write, or use the private variables and methods inside of other classes or structs?

If so, why would you do this? How would you know when to use this? What advantage does this have over not using encapsulation? If possible, could an example be provided of some "bad" code that would benefit from encapsulation?

Thanks for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: Just about any basic OO programming text book should cover this, as does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming).  The idea is to separate the object's interface from its implementation.  The consumer of an object only needs to understand the external interface or _contract_.  The class implementer can do what he needs to to provide that interface.  But, this isn't really a good question for this site - this place is better at "here's a problem I'm trying to solve, here's my code I'm trying to solve it with, what's going on" kind of questions.

Comment: It's essentially bullshit. Was a good idea that got lost somewhere in the mix. Do it however you like and forget about the theories of coding. I agree. Full access, all the time. Let me do it. Let me mess it up. I'll figure it out.

Comment: @Confused Encapsulation isn't really about restricting access to prevent bugs. It is about keeping implementation details hidden so making changes to part of a system doesn't require rewriting half of your codebase.

Comment: @CaTs That's what `Interface` does

Comment: @LeY An interface is certainly a tool you can use to encapsulate implementation details but it is still easy to create an interface that fails to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encapsulation is used to more explicitly define [intended] behavior of a class.

Say you have a `Person` class like so:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

A [real] Persons age is only ever going to go up, so why would you allow anyone to reassign it?

Instead you can encapsulate the age so that it has to follow its intended behavior (at the cost of writing a bit more code to handle assigning / getting the value) like so:

```
public class Person
{
    private int _age = 0;
    public int Age { get => _age;  }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void Birthday()
    {
        _age += 1;
    }
}
```

This way you can guarantee that the age will never go down.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So is encapsulation just used to prevent mistakes that could happen? (like accidently subtracting a number from "age" or making a negative age?)

Comment: @Bretinat0r In a nutshell, yes, that is how I would use it. To make it more obvious to the consumer that the class / type handles this value specially / has special meaning / only certain values are valid and as such, _please_ don't touch it.

Comment: And the consumer would be anyone reading the code? Like another programmer working on the same project or anyone who happened to be reading the source code of a program? Thanks for all this information, you've been really helpful!

Comment: Exactly, the consumer would be anyone (or anything) that could use / read your code (including yourself, say in a few days/months/years after you forget what the code was meant to do). @LeY sums it up very well as 'they [the consumer] will not have all the implementation detail of _your_ class in their mind.'

Answer (score 2):

To put my two cents in.

For Encapsulation, there are basically 2 reasons.

1. Protection.
2. Organization.

You must realize that the code you wrote is not only for yourself , but for other people to read and use (and they can't change your code), especially when you creating a library or framework. and when other people use your class/library , they will not have all the implementation detail of your class in their mind. They expect your code will work properly when use intuitively.

**Organization:**

To put relative information in the correct place. For example in c# `List<T>` has a property `Count`, It's natural to keep tracking how many items in your list and it's natural for the user to ask how many items in my list. It should be the responsibility of the `List` class to track it and much easier. what if you not providing this property. The use have to track it them-self. Every time you want to know how many items in the list, you have to write duplicated code and logic to count it yourself. It is very easy to make mistake when you track it outside of your 'List' and hard to make code change when it happened on many places.The `Count` information naturally belong to your `List` class, and it should be naturally kept there. Every time you want to know the Count , just ask your `List` Object.

**Protection:**

To protect your object internal state always correct through the usage.
Same example from about. The 'Count' property actually is public read and private write.
When you implement `Add` `Remove`, you will remember to increase or decrease the `Count` , you will remember to protect your `Count` to sync with how many item in the list and never go below 0. Imagine if there is no Encapsulation, everything is public. There is nothing stop the user or yourself after 10 years from doing `Count = -100` (believe me, other users or yourself after 10 years will do this), then your `List` Object become totally none-sense. And it will create many bugs that hard to find , even cause real word huge damage, never underestimate what damage a program 
bug can do.

Comment: So for organization you'd use encapsulation to "encapsulate" methods that relate to the property(s) in one class? And for protection you'd use encapsulation to stop the programmer(s) from making mistakes in the code?

Comment: So for protection, encapsulation reminds the programmer what NOT to do?

Comment: @Bretinat0r not reminding, it is more like enforcing programmer use your class as you designed. With a public property, you basically tell the user that this property can change manually and my class still will behave properly.